# Project Euler #8 in Python:

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find the greatest product of thirteen adjacent digits in this 1000-digit number,
This code works for " the four adjacent digits" but it doesn't work with "the thirteen adjacent digits",
I've tried to figure out why but I couldn't.

```
numbers = '''73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''

li = list()
for line in numbers.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    for number in line:
        li.append(int(number))


def multiplyList(li):
    result = 1
    for x in li:
        result *= x
    return result


multiplication_list = list()
biggest = 0
for number in li:

    if len(multiplication_list) < 13:
        multiplication_list.append(number)
    elif len(multiplication_list) == 13:
        result = multiplyList(multiplication_list)
        if result > biggest:
            biggest = result
        multiplication_list.clear()

print(biggest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is that you continue to look at all of the values in the list, scanning through it like a window over a moving scroll, but every time you get to 13 characters, you are starting over from the start.

Instead of `clear` try `pop(0)`

---

It should be noted that your approach is far from optimal. You should think about whether it is even required to re-run the multiplication every time.

Comment: I think I solved that issue. The code was also skipping a number if it hit 13.
Do you think a sliding window would be better? (I'm not qualified to make something like that)

Comment: sliding window if implemented as a ```deque``` with O(1) ```.popleft()``` method would be even better than O(k) ```.pop(0)``` operations although granted k never exceeds 13

Comment: @mj_codec Won't matter unless processing each window is sped up as well.

Comment: Well, I guess you can divide to reduce the complexity, right? (see alternative solution) I'm skipping DIGITS when I encounter a zero.

Comment: @cwallenpoole thx a lot, I've corrected my faults and the code works now.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 problems with your code:

- You start over when you hit 13 numbers as pointed out by @cwallenpoole
- You skip a number when you hit 13 numbers

I've also replaced the 13 with a constant, and saved the characters as a string such that it's easier to figure out if something goes wrong.

Does that fix your issues?

***Note**: the second solution scales much better*

### CONSTANTS:

```py
import timeit
DIGITS = 69
COUNT = 1_000
NUMBERS = '''73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''
ALL_NUMBERS = [int(x) for x in NUMBERS.replace('\n', '')]
```

### Recomputing approach:

```py
def test_1():
    max_product = 0
    used_digits = []
    for i in range(len(ALL_NUMBERS) - DIGITS + 1):
        multiplication_list = ALL_NUMBERS[i:i + DIGITS]
        product = 1
        for factor in multiplication_list:
            product *= factor
        if max_product < product:
            max_product = product
            used_digits = multiplication_list
    return max_product, "".join([str(i) for i in used_digits])
```

### Alternative solution:

```py
def test_2():
    start = max_product = 0
    current_product = 1
    skip_values = DIGITS - 1
    for i, new_number in enumerate(ALL_NUMBERS):
        if new_number == 0:
            current_product = 1
            skip_values = DIGITS - 1
        elif 0 < skip_values:
            current_product *= new_number
            skip_values -= 1
        else:
            current_product *= new_number
            if max_product < current_product:
                max_product = current_product
                start = i - DIGITS + 1
            current_product //= ALL_NUMBERS[i - DIGITS + 1]
    return max_product, "".join([str(i) for i in ALL_NUMBERS[start:start + DIGITS]])
```

### Benchmark:

```py
print("product digits")
print(*test_1())
print(*test_2())
print("#1", timeit.timeit('''test_1()''', globals=globals(), number= COUNT))
print("#2", timeit.timeit('''test_2()''', globals=globals(), number= COUNT))
```

### Output:

```
product digits
2412446685431734624320887406251212800000000 863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426
2412446685431734624320887406251212800000000 863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426
#1 2.416368225000042
#2 0.1289158959989436
```